# discord.js - отправка сообщения ботом в лс при одобрении заявки

Tags: javascript, discord

У меня есть модальная форма, с помощью которой отправляется "резюме". Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии модератором кнопки "Одобрить", пользователю, который подал заявку, в личные сообщения отправило текст "Заявка одобрена.". Сколько не пытаюсь сделать это, сообщение отправляется тому, кто нажимает кнопку, а не тому, кто подал заявку.

```
    if (interaction.customId === "successTicket") {
      if (
        !Config.TICKET.STAFF_ROLES.some((x) =>
          interaction.member.roles.cache.has(x)
        ) &&
        ![interaction.guild.ownerId].includes(interaction.user.id)
      ) {
        await interaction.deferReply({ ephemeral: true });
    
        interaction.followUp({
          content: `Недостаточно прав!`,
          ephemeral: true,
        });
    
        return;
      } else {
        await interaction.update({
          components: [
            new ActionRowBuilder({
              components: [
                ButtonBuilder.from(
                  interaction.message.components[0].components[0]
                ).setDisabled(true),
                ButtonBuilder.from(
                  interaction.message.components[0].components[1]
                ),
                ButtonBuilder.from(
                  interaction.message.components[0].components[2]
                ),
              ],
            }),
          ],
        });
    
        const user = interaction.user;
        const channel = interaction.channel;
    
        // Отправьте сообщение как отдельное сообщение
        channel.send(`<@${interaction.user.id}> одобрил заявку.`);
        user.send(`<@${interaction.user.id}> дальше следуй по инструкции из канала <#1145112070665293977>\nНе забудь архивировать заявку.`,
        );
    
        return;
      }
    }
```

Сейчас код выглядит так. Кто может написать код, который будет отправлять сообщение тому, кто подал заявление, помогите, пожалуйста